# How to remove/replace words from List columns if available

Tags: c#, string, linq

I have `List<Product>` where `ProductName` may have any of word like `*Nokia, NoDevice, iPhone*`.

**Example:** `SIS.Pragati.Nokia.OST, SIS.Trividyaa.iPhone.OST, SIS.OLM.NoDevice.OST` etc

```
public class Product
{ 
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string ProeductType { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to make an array to remove all characters using linq

```
string[] bunchChar = { ".NoDevice", ".Nokia", ".iPhone"};
```

I am expecting output `List<Product>` column values like this

```
SIS.Pragati.OST, SIS.Trividyaa.OST, SIS.OLM.OST
```

How can I remove words from list?

Comment: So do you expect a list of products with names `SIS.Pragati.OST, SIS.Trividyaa.OST, SIS.OLM.OST` as output?

Comment: Could you please post what you have tried using LINQ ?

Comment: @Sweeper - Product names is not exact but those words are exact what I want to remove. Thank you.

Comment: Could you, please, provide an *example* of the desired outcome? Do you want `Product[]` with modified `ProductName`, modified `ProductName` as `string[]`?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko - Please see my updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using `Aggregate` in order to perform *all* possible removes which are mentioned in `bunchChar` (i.e. aggregate all removes in each `ProductName`):

```
List<Product> products = ...

string[] bunchChar = { ".NoDevice", ".Nokia", ".iPhone"};

string[] result = products
  .Select(product => bunchChar
     .Aggregate(product.ProductName, (name, bunch) => name.Replace(bunch, "")))
  .ToArray();
```

**Edit:** in case you want to return `List<Product>` you can exploit the same idea.

```
List<Product> result = products
  .Select(product => new Product() {
     // We modify Product Name
     ProductName = bunchChar
       .Aggregate(product.ProductName, (name, bunch) => name.Replace(bunch, ""))),
     // While keeping ProductType intact 
     ProductType = product.ProductType
   }
  .ToList();
```

**Edit 2:** If you want to modify *existing* list (i.e. modify all `Product` within `products`):

```
foreach (var product in products)
  product.ProductName = bunchChar
    .Aggregate(product.ProductName, (name, bunch) => name.Replace(bunch, "")));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, But here you selecting only one column. I need all columns of list.

Comment: @r15: Shall we return `string[] result` or `Product[] result`?

Comment: I need `List<Product>` in output.

Comment: I want to get modified only `ProductName`, not `ProductType`. `ProductType` values should be same.

Comment: @r15: please, edit your question then (it's unclear, that you want a *list*, not an *array*, of `Product`, not of `string`); a *good example* is what we badly need.

Comment: I am sorry for confusion. I wrote array(to show my effort) what I tried. Simple I need to remove specific words from one of list's column. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
products.ForEach(p => p.ProductName = p.ProductName.Replace(bunchChar[0], "").Replace(bunchChar[1], "").Replace(bunchChar[2], ""));
```

If you'd make `bunchChar` also `List<string>` you could make it more concise:

```
products.ForEach(p => bunchChar.ForEach(bc => p.ProductName = p.ProductName.Replace(bc, "")));
```